# Datasheet for Keyes IR Transmitter (KY-005) wanted

Tags: voltage, current, infrared, datasheet, transmitter

Can someone help me find the datasheet for the Keyes IR Transmitter (KY-005)?

I know how the pins work, I just need to figure out its voltage drop and how much current should go through it.

Thanks! :)

Image of the component: [image]

Comment: I'm guessing 1.6V - 1.8V, and 15-20mA max.. perhaps put 5mA through it and measure the voltage dropped over the LED? You should be able to find similar 5mm (or is that 3mm diameter??) IR LEDs and their ratings, and it should be mostly in line with those. Be conservative though, run it at half the expected max current just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation :) Unfortunately I have no equipment to measure the voltage drop, unless this is somehow possible using the Arduino board. Anyway, the led is going to be close to the receiving unit, so it won't need to be at maximum brightness.

Comment: you are driving the LED with the Arduino output pin?

Comment: anyway you can actually use the Arduino to sense the voltage over the LED. Use an ADC input (analogue pin) connected to the node between the resistor and the LED (if the LED goes from the resistor to ground, this is better). The conversion result will be 0-1024, which represents 0V-5V in step resolution of 1/1024.